# Oozie executing hadoop commands in shell action as yarn

Tags: oozie

Environment : Hortonworks Sandbox HDP 2.2.4

Issue : Unable to run the hadoop commands present in the shell scripts as a root user. The oozie job is getting triggered as a root user, but when the hadoop fs or any mapreduce command is executed, then it runs as yarn user. As yarn, doesn’t have access to some of the file system , so the shell script is failing to execute. Let me know what changes I need to do , for making it run the hadoop commands as root user.

Answer (score 1):

It is an expected behaviour to get Yarn in place whenever we are invoking shell actions in oozie. Yarn user only have the capabilities to run shell actions. One thing we can do is to give access permissions to Yarn on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a shell script question than an Oozie question. In theory, Oozie job runs as the user who submits the job. In a kerberos' env, the user is whoever signed in with keytab/password.

Once job is running on Hadoop cluster, in order to change the ownership of command, you can use "sudo" within your shell script. In your case, you may also want to make sure user "yarn" is allowed to sudo to the commands you want to execute.

Comment: Shad Amez is asking to give a fix to the oozie issue. sudo in shell action is not permitted in Oozie.

Answer (score 0):

Add below property to workflow:

HADOOP_USER_NAME=${wf:user()}